# how can i rebuild npm modules in angular?

Tags: angular, npm, module

I have some changes in one of my **npm modules** in my angular project but it has no effect in my build version.

can anyone help me?

Comment: What changes? What change did you expect to see?

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest cleaning and reinstalling:

1. Delete `node_modules`
2. Delete `package-lock.json`
3. Run `npm i`

Comment: I Removed Ng-Bootstrap From My Angular App, And I Had To Just Reset The node_modules Folder. This Helped. Thanks.

Comment: Had to remove all preinstall resolutions for npm audit's, then it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you are upgrading your dependencies. Check your `package-lock.json` and search for the name of your package, there you will see which version you've installed.

To upgrade a dependency you can do `npm upgrade <name-package>`

This command would upgrade your packaged depending on the tiles set in your `package.json` (ie: "^1.x" won't upgrade automatically to version 2.x).
Change there the set up if you need to.

The quick solution (not the best practice) is removing and installing again (if you don't need any to handle any special concern about your dependency version):

`npm uninstall <package-name>    // To clean the package-lock.json references
npm install <package-name>`